# Put image over image

Tags: html, css

Some know how to put image over other over image?
I tried couple times with CSS and got stuck

HTML:

```
<div>
    <!--background-->
    <img src="pics/bg.png" width="100%" class="bg">
    <!--icon-->
    <img src="pics/icon.png" class="logo">
</div>
```

Comment: **display: grid** on the div and then **grid-area: 1/1/-1/-1** on the images

Answer (score 0):

To layer images you can position them with `absolute` positioning. For example, if your `img` elements were to have `id`’s of `img1` and `img2`, this is how the CSS should look to stack `img2` on top of `img1` (with some additional padding to make it obvious):

```
#img1 {
position: absolute;
}

#img2 {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
}
```

You could also add a `z-index: <number_here>` property to both of the CSS rules for each of the images. Here, the image with the higher number for its respective `z-index` would show above the other. The `z-index` is used for stacking elements depth-wise (think x, y, z coordinate system - the z adds depth).

If you don’t know how to add an `id` field to an HTML element, check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to absolutely position your icon (`.logo`) image.

An `position: absolute` element is positioned in relation to its nearest ancestor that is positioned. By making the parent `<div>` positioned, you can place the `.logo` on top and adjust its placement with `top` and `left`.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px blue solid;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--background-->
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/100">

  <!--top-->
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/75" class="logo">
</div>
```